# Что делает этот кусок кода? Как эта конструкция назывется?

Tags: python

Наткнулся на GitHub'е на вот такой странный код. Что это?

```
def rk_iter(u, v, t, dt):
    ...

runge_kutta = lambda u, v, tmax, n: iterate(rk_iter, u, v, tmax, n)

print "runge_kutta=", runge_kutta(u0, v0, tmax, n)
```

Как это называется? Зачем тут lambda u, v, tmax, n:?

Почему нельзя просто передать аргументы в функцию?

Вот ссылка на полный код, если без него никак не ответить https://gist.github.com/mblondel/487187

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как это называется? Зачем тут lambda u, v, tmax, n:?

лямбда или безымянная функция

Лямбды хороши, когда нужно сделать что-то в одном месте, например заковыристое условие для фильтра:

```
new_items = list(filter(lambda x: x > 1 and x < 50 and x % 2 == 1, items))
```

Можно конечно и функцию создать, но если у вас в коде несколько таких мест, то лямбды помогут упростить его, убрав лишние сущности (функции)

---

> Почему нельзя просто передать аргументы в функцию?

Возможно, автор экономил код, т.к. строчка с лябмдой это тоже самое что:

```
def runge_kutta(u, v, tmax, n):
    return iterate(rk_iter, u, v, tmax, n)
```

Мне лично, вариант с полноценной функцией больше нравится.

Comment: Мне кажется для читаемости кода полезно всё писать в развёрнутом виде без всяких lambda